# How to flush a list to memory after being modified by a thread in OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I have a list that is shared between 2 threads on OpenMP. The list is passed as a reference to an external function called by each thread. In the function, each thread will generate a private list, lock the shared list, join the private list with the shared list via splice(). I used omp_lock_t when the splice() is happening in each thread, but the resulting shared list after the 2 threads finish is not correct as if the other thread does not see the changes made to the shared list by the current thread. What should I do?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    list<string> shared_list;
    omp_lock_t l0;
    omp_init_lock(&l0);

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
    {
        external_function(shared_list, &l0);
    }
}


external function(list<string>& shared_list, omp_lock_t* l0)
{
    list<string> local_list;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        local_list.push_back("Aloha");
    }

    omp_set_lock(l0);
    shared_list.splice(shared_list.end(), local_list);
    omp_unset_lock(l0);
}
```

Comment: [Edit] your question to include a [mcve] that we can compile.  Include expected and actual output.  Compare with the output you get without the `#pragma omp`.  Then consider why you're getting your observed results.